# Electric-pair-mode not detected for some characters with German keyboard layout

Tags: macos, emacs, autocomplete, keyboard

So I am trying to get a grip on Emacs 24.5 running on Mac Os 10.10.4.
I have a German keyboard and decided to keep the    alt     -key as Meta. As I still have to use it for some essential characters such as [ , | and } (resembling alt-5, alt-6 and alt-9) it decided to go with this solution:

```
(global-set-key "\M-5" (lambda () (interactive) (insert “[“)))
(global-set-key "\M-6" (lambda () (interactive) (insert “]”)))
(global-set-key "\M-7" (lambda () (interactive) (insert “|”)))
...
```

When I am enabling electric pair mode in the init-file with `(electric-pair-mode 1)` , it works just fine with ( ) and " ", but not with [ ], { } and ' '.
I then tried a different appraoch by using this code to swap the keys:

```
(defun redefine-key (key char)
  (define-key function-key-map key char)
  (global-unset-key key))
(redefine-key "\M-5" "[")
(redefine-key "\M-6" "]")
...
```

Interestingly, the pair feature now works for the square brackets [ ], but not the curly ones { }. Although the ' key on the German keyboard is not even related to the alt-key (it's accessed by the shift-key), it doesn't work at all. 
Same results for the autopair package, btw.

Please, anyone? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way `electric-pair-mode` works is by installing a callback function ("hook") called `electric-pair-post-self-insert-function`. As the name suggests, this hook gets invoked by Emacs after the function `self-insert-command` runs -- which is after you type a key.

And that's your problem here: calling `insert` is not the same as typing a key. It does not invoke `self-insert-command` and consequently, the above hook function never gets called. Even worse, you cannot simply invoke `self-insert-command` programmatically because, unlike `insert`, it doesn't take a parameter for the character to insert. You have to jump through hoops a bit, but you could try the following:

```lisp
(global-set-key "\M-5" (lambda (&optional N) (interactive "P") (insert-as-self ?\[ N)))
(global-set-key "\M-6" (lambda (&optional N) (interactive "P") (insert-as-self ?\] N)))
(global-set-key "\M-7" (lambda (&optional N) (interactive "P") (insert-as-self ?\| N)))

(defun insert-as-self (CHAR N)
  (let ((last-command-event CHAR)
        (repeat (if N N 1)))
    (self-insert-command repeat)))
```

Here, we locally set the special variable `last-command-event` to "fake" a key stroke before calling `self-insert-command`.

For curly braces and quotes to work, you have to do two things: First, add the respective `(global-set-key ...)` definitions to your .emacs file, similar to the ones above. Then let `electric-pair-mode` know that you want quotes and curlies to be handled by it by adding the following line to your .emacs file:

```lisp
(setq electric-pair-pairs '((?\' . ?\') (?\" . ?\") (?\{ . ?\}))) –
```

Comment: Awesome, solved. My bad, ' ' and { } are doubled by `electric-pair-mode`  in CSS mode, but not the other ones. Thx.

Comment: @KaiMx I updated the answer by inserting my comment about curly braces. Would you consider deleting your first comment? It refers to the previous version of my answer and would now be a bit confusing.